# How to improve MongoDb performance when updating many objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, import

I am trying to read a JSON file which contains about 200.000 lines, each containing a small JSON document of the form:

```
{
   <some key properties>,
   <some 2-3 properties>,   // unimportant for this question
   updateCounter1: -1,
   updateCounter2: 0,
   updateCounter3: 3
}
```

Now I want to insert this into my MongoDb, and the documents shall have the following form:

```
{
   <some key properties>,
   <some 2-3 properties>,
   counter1: 3748,
   counter2: 722,
   counter3: 2848
}
```

So that means, for every line in the original file with the same key-attributes, their counter-updates shall be added on top of what is stored in the database already.

In my code, it looks like this currently:

```
         let item = {
            query: {
               refSpHash: ...,
               gender: ...,
               age: ...,
               state: ...,
               district:  ...
            },
            set: {
               refSp: ...,
               msgSp: ...
            },
            counters: {
               counter1: 1,
               counter2: -2,
               counter3: 4
            }
         };

         // (....)

         let update = { $set: _.assign({}, item.set, item.query), $inc: item.counters };

         collection.updateOne(item.query, update, { upsert: true }, (err) => { ... });
```

So I am using the `$inc` operator to do a relative increase/decrease of the DB-value as given by the input JSON, and `$set` for the rest of the properties.
The above piece of code is executed for every single line in the input file, and I am using `async.eachSeries` to import every line one by one.

Now the issue is, while it *seems* to work, its taking ages to complete. I have started the import like half an hour ago, and it is still importing. So most likely I have just written some really bad code.

Could anyone help me to improve the importing-logic, so that the processing is faster?

Comment: Have you thought of JSON Streams?

Comment: Nope, don't know what that is.

Comment: https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream

Comment: How will this help inserting objects into MongoDB? The input-file is parsed within 1-2 seconds, but the insertion of JS-objects into the MongoDB is what takes the most time here.

Comment: Try to combine it with http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite.

Comment: Are the fields in the query part indexed?

Comment: Nope, I guess not. I've also changed it now to a single key field (hash of the previous key fields), but you're right, I shall create an index for the key field(s).

Comment: @Joe Great, actually the processing time just went down to about 2 minutes :) If you add the hint as answer, I can accept it.